# How to improve index performance in Elasticsearch with too many fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an index with thousands of columns. I try to index 10,000,000 documents in the cluster. It costs about 3 hours.

I tried [some methods](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html) to turning the index speed and it is still slow.

How can I turning the speed for such an index with thousands of fields and more than 100,000,000 documents?

Answer (score 1):

What is the hardware configuration of your cluster? How much memory does the Java Heap have? How many cores? What is the speed of your disk?

Also, where is your infrastructure? On premises or a cloud service?

You really need all the fields in the document? How is the mapping of your index?

If you already tried the methods to improve performance, maybe there is not much else you can do, millions of documents which thousands of fields each one will really take time to index.

Comment: Thanks. The hardware is unchangeable so I didn't talk about it in this question. And the I need all the fields and all documents. I am not sure how filed number affects index performance.

Comment: More fields leads to a larger document size which takes more time to index, basically the index speed depends on the document size, the memory available for the JAVA heap, the memory available for the system, how fast is your cores and how fast is your disk, if you can't change any of those things you can't improve the index speed.

How are you sending the data to Elasticsearch? Maybe you can try some tweaks on that side.